# Prestashop new javascript variables from database

Tags: javascript, database, variables, prestashop

I see in PS code some prestashop variables in head section. For example "var prestashop". I can access these variables in js files for example "prestashop.currency.iso_code" will print "EUR" in my case.

But how can I add new variables? I need to add all available currencies with conversions rates.

Answer (score 0):

It starting to be bad habit answering own questions...

```
 public function hookHeader($params)
    {   

        Media::addJsDef(
            array(
                'currency_id' => (int)$this->context->currency->id,
                'conversion_rate' => Context::getContext()->currency->getConversionRate(),
             )
        );
    }
```